# Getting an error on sending an embed message of the player/user's balance

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

The following is the code that has to do with the balance, as u might notice that there are various currencies and for that I have done add_field quite a few times, it would be really nice if you could tell me if there is a way to do it in a shorter and/or easier way...anyways coming to the main problem.
Main.py

```
async def equilibrium(user: discord.Member):
    db = await aiosqlite.connect("balance_db.db")
    cursor = await db.cursor()
    await cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM bal WHERE user_id = {user.id} ")
    result = await cursour.fetchall()
    print (result)

    if result:
        return

    if not result:
        await cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO bal(user_id, cash, crystals, event_pearls, weapon_shards, fusion_earring, merging_stones, enhancing_stones) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (user.id, 500, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))

        await db.commit()
        await cursor.close()
        await db.close()

@bot.command(aliases=['bal'])
async def balance(ctx, user:discord.Member=None):
    if user is None:
        user = ctx.author

    await equilibrium(user=user)

    db = await aiosqlite.connect("balance_db.db")
    cursor = await db.cursor()
    await cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM bal WHERE user_id = {user.id} ")

    balem = discord.Embed(title=f"**{user.mention}'s balance**", color=discord.Color.blue())
    balem.add_field(name="Cash:", value=f":GenesisCrystal: {result[1]}", inline=True)
    balem.add_field(name="crystals:", value=f":GenesisCrystal: {result[2]}", inline=True)
    balem.add_field(name="event pearls:", value=f":GenesisCrystal: {result[3]}", inline=True)
    balem.add_field(name="weapon shards:", value=f":GenesisCrystal: {result[4]}", inline=True)
    balem.add_field(name="fusion earring:", value=f":GenesisCrystal: {result[5]}", inline=True)
    balem.add_field(name="merging stones:", value=f":GenesisCrystal: {result[6]}", inline=True)
    balem.add_field(name="enhancing stones:", value=f":GenesisCrystal: {result[7]}", inline=True)
    await ctx.send(embed=balem)
```

upon testing and doing '(serverprefix) bal' it gives the following error:

```
 INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
2022-09-12 23:45:43 INFO     discord.gateway Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: 7338538a9635f5cf39dba129dc8621fa).
[]
2022-09-12 23:45:44 ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command balance
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 190, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\Desktop\CodingPAIN.py", line 50, in balance
    balem.add_field(name="Cash:", value=f":GenesisCrystal: {result[1]}", inline=True)
IndexError: list index out of range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1347, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 986, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 199, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: IndexError: list index out of range
The Bot is Online
```

I am using the following:
python version 9.3x (9.3.13 precisely)
aiosqlite as the database (i know about the mordern aiosqlite method of writing the code, but I am much more familiar with the old, or the sqlite3 method

I am just a beginner, help of any kind would be appriciated

Comment: Please [edit] to include the full traceback of the error and a [mcve] (keyword: *minimal*)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to change `result = await cursor.fetchall()` to `result = await cursour.fetchall()[0]`.

Sqlite's `fetchall()` returns a list of tuples (something like `[(1,), (2,)]`, so you need to index to the first tuple, then loop through that.